# Remove a Dynamically Created Panel from Scroll List

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Hopefully I can articulate this properly. I have a `TScrollBox` on a form. I am adding instances of another form to a dynamically created panel that I am adding to the `TScrollBox` , here is the code I am using to add it.

```
procedure TSettings.AddWFOnclick(Sender: TObject);
var
    dlg : TWFDetail;
    panel: TPanel;
    i    : Integer;
begin
    panel := TPanel.Create(self);

    dlg := TWFDetail.Create(self);

    panel.Parent := WFList;
    panel.clientheight := dlg.height;
    panel.align := alTop;
    panel.Top := 330;
    panel.Left := 0;

    dlg.Parent := panel;
    dlg.align := alClient;

    dlg.visible := True;

    dlg.Show;

end;
```

The above works beautifully to add my form and panel. As seen here:
[image: Add Panel Working]

The issue occurs when I try to close the dlg and remove the panel. I don't have any sample code for that. I have tried a dozen different things and can't seem to figure it out. I am closing the form with a close call on the click of the red X, then the panel remains. Seen here:
[image: The issue]

I need to be able to remove the blank panel and shift everything up. I just can't seem to wrap my head around it since the panel is being created dynamically.

The parenting structure is `TScrollBox` > `TPanel` > `MyForm`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you must delete the form's `Parent` panel after the form is closed (even when I don't like that much). Better yet, delete the `Parent` panel instead of closing the form by that red cross button.

Comment: The problem I am having is I can't seem to access the forms parent panel to delete it. My first attempt was to delete the Parent panel witht he red X click but I don't seem to grasp the way to access it without a Name;

Comment: And anyway why not use frames? They are there just for that...

Comment: @JamesW The form.parent is the panel. If you don't free the form (form close action = caHide and not = caFree) you can still access parent.

Comment: `if Parent is TPanel then Parent.Free;` called from that red cross button click event might start the destruction chain (child form, parent panel after). That should in turn realign the scroll box children.

Comment: Even better with @Victoria solution...

Comment: Victoria's info solved it. I was trying to be way more complicated about it. Feel pretty silly now.

Comment: @JamesW I don't know if I can translate correctly from Italian, but here we say It's the Complicating Simple Matter Bureau! ;-)

Comment: Note that this does not solve the issue of realigning the remaining panels. `TScrollBox` WILL NOT do that automatically. You have to do it manually after freeing the desired Panel. You should store the Panels in a `T(Object)List` that you can loop through when needed. Loop when calculating the `Top` for a newly added Panel. Loop to reset the `Top` of remaining Panels after freeing a panel. Etc

Comment: @BigBother Indeed, frames were designed for a similar purpose, but they have their own complications. I personally hate using them, they're very irritating for me. I much prefer to embed forms.

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm the other way. I prefer to use Frames and never embedded Forms. Frames solve issues related to Form embedding. Frames are designed to be embedded.

Comment: @Remy, automatic realign exists. If you re-parent a control (`TControl.SetParent`) which is in this case caused by the control's (panel) destructor (to `nil`), VCL then notifies control's parent (scroll box) through `TWinControl.RemoveControl` which in turn calls `Realign` (for scroll box).

Comment: Note that `Parent.Free` is not safe called from a button's click handler which is owned by the form which is parented by the panel: *"..  Never explicitly free a component within one of its own event handlers or the event handler of a component it owns or contains. .."*.

Comment: Post a message to the scroll box and free the panel from there.

Comment: @Victoria yes, but that only applies to controls that are actually aligned... Oh, nevermind, I didn't see the OP is using `alTop` alignment for the panels ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `TNorifyEvent` on **TWFDetail** form. Define it:

```
property OnCloseForm:TNotifyEvent read FOnCloseForm write FOnCloseForm;
```

When you close the form, fire the event if assigned:

```
  Self.Close;

  if Assigned(OnCloseForm) then
    OnCloseForm(Self);
```

When you create the form, assign the `OnCloseForm` event:

```
...
dlg.OnCloseForm := CloseForm;
...
```

And define a simple `CloseForm` procedure to free the panel that you use to contain the form:

```
var
  pnl:TPanel;
begin
  if (Sender is TWFDetail) then begin
    if TWFDetail(Sender).Parent is TPanel then begin
      pnl := TPanel(TWFDetail(Sender).Parent);
      pnl.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

There are some other ways to to this, but this work fine.

[image]

Comment: While Vitorias comment to my question gave me an answer that worked, this is very helpful and is along the lines of what I was actually trying to pull off.